# Django Celery and localization problems

Tags: python, django, localization, celery, django-celery

I have a bit problem with celery, I don't know why its using different localization then my django project.
Here is error:

```
    [2012-09-05 16:15:02,945: ERROR/MainProcess] Task kan.mailing.tasks.resend_task[91430f30-893e-4a75-8cf9-47c4b7ac8f04] raised exception: ImproperlyConfigured("MenuPositionAdmin.list_display[1], 'title_en_us' is not a callable or an attribute of 'MenuPositionAdmin' or found in the model 'MenuPosition'.",)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/necromac/work/kan/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/task/trace.py", line 224, in trace_task
    R = retval = fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/necromac/work/kan/src/kan/mailing/tasks.py", line 44, in resend_task
    result=my_mail_send(t, c, subject=mailing_ob.subject, to=[mail_list_entry_ob.email.email] ,from_email=mailing_ob.reply_to )
  File "/home/necromac/work/kan/src/kan/utils/helpers.py", line 291, in my_mail_send
    text_content = template.render(context)
```

Project Langueges are this, so i have no idea from where celery got _en_us tables.

```
LANGUAGES = (('pl', _('pl')),
             ('en', _('en')),
             ('de', _('de')),
             ('ru', _('ru')),
             ('fr', _('fr')),
             ('es', _('es')))

LANGUAGES_AVAILABLE = ('pl','en', 'de')
```

and this is a source of problem

```
html_content = template.render(context)
```

Comment: Are you sure the Celery worker is running with those settings?  Please note that the celery worker does not activate translation, but there's an utility in django-celery to help with this: https://github.com/celery/django-celery/blob/master/djcelery/common.py

Comment: when i start celery i have something like this
    `Start from server, version: 8.0, properties: {u'platform':  u'Erlang/OTP', u'product': u'RabbitMQ', u'version': u'1.7.2', u'copyright': u'Copyright (C) 2007-2010 LShift Ltd., Cohesive Financial Technologies LLC., and Rabbit Technologies Ltd.', u'information': u'Licensed under the MPL.  See http://www.rabbitmq.com/'}, mechanisms: [u'PLAIN', u'AMQPLAIN'], locales: [u'en_US']`
can this locales be source of my problem? if it is then how can i change it?

Comment: that is extremely unlikely as that is just the locales that the rabbitmq broker speaks, and shouldn't effect your system